# Excel - Replace values in one column by values in another column

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I have a lot fo data in Excel spreadsheet. One of the column keeps the ISO code of the country. I would like to replace this value with the whole name of the country. Of course there are lists of ISO codes and corresponding country names on the internet, but I would like to know, if there's a better way than Ctrl+H thousand times for each ISO code value.

Thank you in advance.

Example: (I would like to replace values in A by these in E based on value from D)

[image: Example]

Comment: by reference note the `$` vs without when referencing other cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a new column adjacent to the column with ISO codes.  Then you can perform an index(match()).

Using your example above the formula in B1 would look like this:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$5,MATCH($A1,$D$1:$D$5,0))
```

You should then be able to drag the formula down and refresh to find a list of country names appearing next to your ISO codes.

- NOTE: I would keep the ISO > Country Name master table on a separate worksheet for easy maintenance and clarity.